# JavaScript: How to validate a string is really a string

Tags: javascript, string, validation

I'm creating a framework where I'm giving developers the ability to create objects with custom types using defined metadata structures in XML:

```xml
<class name="Class">
    <attr name="id" type="Yuid" mandatory="true"/>
    <attr name="name"type="YString"/>
</class>
```

then in javascript/typescript you can do something like:

```js
 const instance = new Class({
    name: "bob"
 });
```

The idea is to add validators to the class attribute generators to assert the XML schema is valid.

For simple primitives I was using the primitive constructors like `str = new String(str)` until we started running into some weird issues when displaying this data. To illustrate:

```js
const thang = new String("thang");
const theng = String("theng");
const thing = "thing";
const thong = String({ rick: "sanchez" });
const thung = new String({ rick: "sanchez" });

console.log(thang, typeof thang); // [String: 'thang'] 'object
console.log(theng, typeof theng); // theng string
console.log(thing, typeof thing); // thing string
console.log(thong, typeof thong); // [object Object] string
console.log(thung, typeof thung); // [String: '[object Object]'] 'object'

console.log({}.toString(), typeof {}.toString()); // [object Object] string
console.log("abc".toString(), typeof "abc".toString()); // abc string
console.log([1, 2, 3].toString(), typeof [1, 2, 3].toString()); // 1,2,3 string
console.log((5).toString(), typeof (5).toString()); // 5 string

console.log(`thang is ${thang}`); // thang is thang
console.log(`theng is ${thang}`); // theng is theng
console.log(`thing is ${thang}`); // thing is thing
console.log(`thong is ${thong}`); // thong is [object Object]
console.log(`thung is ${thung}`); // thung is [object Object]
```

TypeScript hints are the same, I would be getting strings in all cases, but reality is a bit different so how can I be entirely sure than I can transform any value into string?

Comment: `new String` returns an object. To convert any value to a string, call `String` without `new`.

Comment: You should never use `new String`

Comment: @FelixKling check what happened when i did `thong = String({})`

Comment: Yes, that's the expected value when converting an object to a string. Do you expect/want something else? It's not quite clear to me what your question is about tbh.

Comment: I expect to log/display a string and see the value of the string, not [object Object]

Comment: But that's the string's value. Converting an object to a string results in the value `[object Object]`. So you are seeing the value of the string. Maybe you expect an object to be converted to a *different* string value?

Comment: well when it expects a string and you give it an object it runs toString on it and you get what you get...

Comment: I guess I can explicitly compare the result of the transformation to "[object Object]" to validate the user is providing the right types to the class constructor

Comment: It's still completely unclear to me what the issue is. Whether it's with using `new String` instead of using a string literal or `String` or something else. Can you provide an example of what you are actually trying to achieve? How does all the `new String`, `String` code relate to your first example?

Comment: Re-reading the question it seems I was unclear what the purpose of the validation was. I need to validate that the data being supplied to the class constructor is actually compatible with the declared type on the XML metadata.

Comment: The XML metadata no only creates a java script class one can use but also MySQL tables. So, if you create a YEmail type, it validates the value against a regex expression, an Yuid generates a UUID and so on

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
const thang = new String("thang");
```

use:

```
const thang = "thang";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the typeof check, you could check for the object's constructor's name

```
> var x = new String('hello')
> x
[String: 'hello']
> typeof x
'object'
> x.constructor.name
'String'
```